# Render specific page on NodeJS error

Tags: node.js, express

How can I render a specific page when an error occurs in my Node app?
For example catch all errors and render a 404 when they happen...

By the way I am using Express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Add an error handling as last piece of middleware
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.render("404");
});
```

There is a specific error handling middleware for this `express.errorHandler`

Comment: Getting an "object #<IncomingMessage> has no render method" error

Comment: @user971956 I forgot the order of the parameters, fixed it now. `(err, req, res, next)`

Answer (score 2):

You should use `app.error()` as described in [the guide](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#error-handling).

```
app.get('/error', function(req, res, next){
   throw new Error('oops');
});
app.error(function(err, req, res, next){
   // do whatever you want
});
```